# Codeigniter throws an error and do not send confirmation mail to user

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I make a registration page in codeigniter, everything is good but when I click register it inserts all data to the database however it does not send a confirmation letter to mail and gives an error:

> THE FOLLOWING SMTP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED: 99 CANNOT ASSIGN REQUESTED
>   ADDRESS UNABLE TO SEND EMAIL USING PHP SMTP. YOUR SERVER MIGHT NOT BE
>   CONFIGURED TO SEND MAIL USING THIS METHOD.
>
> DATE: FRI, 23 JUN 2017
>   16:15:55 +0300 FROM: "WTF"  RETURN-PATH:
>    TO: LUT_MILCEY@MAIL.RU SUBJECT:
>   =?UTF-8?Q?VERIFY=20YOUR=20EMAIL=20AD?==?UTF-8?Q?DRESS?= REPLY-TO:  USER-AGENT: CODEIGNITER X-SENDER:
>   LUT.MILCEY@GMAIL.COM X-MAILER: CODEIGNITER X-PRIORITY: 3 (NORMAL)
>   MESSAGE-ID: <594D148BCAB8E@GMAIL.COM> MIME-VERSION: 1.0

Here is my controller:

```
<?php
class User extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url', 'security'));
        $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'email'));
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->model('User_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->register();
    }



    function register()
    {
        //set validation rules
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|alpha|min_length[3]|max_length[30]|is_unique[instructors.instructors_slug]xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mail', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[instructors.mail]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'password', 'trim|required|md5');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Confirm Password', 'trim|required|md5|matches[password]');
        $to_email= $this->input->post('mail');

        $data['courses'] = $this->Popular_courses_model->get_popular_courses();
        $data['news'] = $this->News_model->get_news();


        //validate form input
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            // fails


            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('pages/index', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        }
        else
        {
            //insert the user registration details into database
            $data = array(
                'instructors_slug' => $this->input->post('username'),
                'mail' => $to_email,
                'password' => $this->input->post('password')
            );

            // insert form data into database
            if ($this->User_model->insertUser($data)) {



                if ($this->User_model->sendEmail($to_email)) {
                    // successfully sent mail
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">You are Successfully Registered! Please confirm the mail sent to your Email-ID!!!</div>');
                    redirect('user/register');
                }
                else
                {
                    // error
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">'.$to_email.'  gondermir '.$this->email->print_debugger().'</div>');
                    redirect('user/register');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // error
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">daxil elemir</div>');
                    redirect('user/register');
            }
        }
    }



    function verify($hash=NULL)
    {
        if ($this->User_model->verifyEmailID($hash))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('verify_msg','<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your Email Address is successfully verified! Please login to access your account!</div>');
            redirect('user/register');
        }
        else
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('verify_msg','<div class="alert alert-danger text-center">Sorry! There is error verifying your Email Address!</div>');
            redirect('user/register');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

And here is my model:

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    function __construct()
    {
        // Call the Model constructor
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //insert into user table
    function insertUser($data)
    {
        return $this->db->insert('instructors', $data);
    }


    //send verification email to user's email id
    function sendEmail($to_email)
    {
        $from_email = 'lut.milcey@gmail.com'; //change this to yours
        $subject = 'Verify Your Email Address';
        $message = 'Dear User,<br /><br />Please click on the below activation link to verify your email address.<br /><br /> http://www.wtf.az/user/verify/' . md5($to_email) . '<br /><br /><br />Thanks<br />Mydomain Team';

        //configure email settings
        $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
        $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; //change this
        $config['smtp_port'] = '465';
        $config['smtp_user'] = 'lut.milcey@gmail.com'; //change this
        $config['smtp_pass'] = 'mypass'; //change this
        $config['mailtype'] = 'html';
        $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
        $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
        $config['newline'] = "\r\n";
        $this->email->initialize($config);

        //send mail
        $this->load->library('email');
        $this->email->from($from_email, 'WTF');
        $this->email->to($to_email);
        $this->email->subject($subject);
        $this->email->message($message);
        return $this->email->send();
    }

    //activate user account
    function verifyEmailID($key)
    {
        $data = array('status' => 1);
        $this->db->where('md5(mail)', $key);
        return $this->db->update('instructors', $data);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: My gut feeling is that it couldn't bind to the port to send mail. You should create an [mcve] with only [PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mail.php) and see if you get the same result. You should also update your question with OS and web server with versions.

Answer (score 0):

try to change this code in your User_model

```
$config['protocol'] = 'smtp';
```

to

```
$config['protocol'] = 'mail';
```

or refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628418/codeigniter-smtp-unable-to-connect/44637852#44637852)